# What's a simple method to dump pipe input to a file? (Linux)

Tags: linux, pipe, exim

I'm looking for a little shell script that will take anything piped into it, and dump it to a file.. for email debugging purposes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The unix command tee does this.

```
man tee
```

Answer (score 12):

You're not alone in needing something similar... in fact, someone wanted that functionality decades ago and developed [tee](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tee) :-)

Of course, you can redirect stdout directly to a file in any shell using the > character:

```
echo "hello, world!" > the-file.txt
```

Answer (score 11):

```
cat > FILENAME
```

Answer (score 5):

The standard unix tool tee can do this. It copies input to output, while also logging it to a file.

Answer (score 2):

Use Procmail. Procmail is your friend. Procmail is made for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

Use `<<command>> | tee <<file>>` for piping a command `<<command>>` into a file `<<file>>`.

This will also show the output.

Comment: This solution has also the advantage that you receive an error message on `stderr` if you are missing the permissions to create the file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to analyze it in the script:

```
while /bin/true; do
    read LINE
    echo $LINE > $OUTPUT
done
```

But you can simply use cat. If cat gets something on the stdin, it will echo it to the stdout, so you'll have to pipe it to cat >$OUTPUT. These will do the same. The second works for binary data also.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a shell script, try this:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec cat >/path/to/file
```

Answer (score 1):

If exim or sendmail is what's writing into the pipe, then procmail is a good answer because it'll give you file locking/serialization and you can put it all in the same file.

If you just want to write into a file, then
  - tee > /tmp/log.$$
or
  - cat > /tmp/log.$$
might be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Huh? I guess, I don't get the question?

Can't you just end your pipe into a `>> ~file`

For example

```
echo "Foobar" >> /home/mo/dumpfile
```

will append Foobar to the dumpfile (and create dumpfile if necessary). No need for a shell script... Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

if you don't care about outputting the result

```
cat - > filename
```

or

```
cat > filename
```