# Appending to two separate log files

Tags: powershell, logging, append

I am trying to append to two log files at the same time. I am currently having to repeat the output and the append command  `>>`  twice which is giving me repeat code:

```
$log1 = "C:\log1.txt" 
$log2 = "C:\log2.txt"
$output = "Some output to be logged" 
$output >> $log1 
$output >> $log2
```

I have looked into using the `Tee-Object` command and have come up with the following:

```
$output | Tee $log1 >> $log2
```

But this overwrites the first (`$log1`) and appends to the second (`$log2`). So my question is how I get `$log1` not to be overwritten just appended too?

Related question:

[how-to-redirect-a-output-of-a-command-to-two-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625571/how-to-redirect-a-output-of-a-command-to-two-files)

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the `Add-Content` cmdlet:

```
$output | Add-Content -Path $log1,$log2
```