# Printing both on console and to a file

Tags: java, file-io, console

I have already looked into several SFO [Links e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26029117/java-printing-to-the-console-and-to-a-file) for a solution. What I have is code written by my colleague which has around 30 methods, and involves nested loops. The problem with this is when I try to run the code in eclipse, the console output has the long-tail issue.

What I was looking in was to print the results (intermediate results) on the console as well as on to a file (without making changes to all the sysout commands within all methods).

What I have done now is something like this

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"));
System.setOut(out);
```

But this only write to a file and not on the display.

Comment: Well, you should check if there is a default `OutputStream` that duplicate the output (never checked) or you can write you own class that will write into multiple `OutputSteam` (one inherited, the rest in a `Collection`), then set that instance in `System.out`

Comment: Is this specifically about Eclipse? There is a setting in Eclipse to write all output to a file as well as console - Run Configurations > configuration for what you're running > Common > check Output File and select location.

Answer (score 1):

You could branch your output stream using [TeeOutputStream](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/TeeOutputStream.html) to print to both console and a text file

Answer (score 1):

Extending `PrintStream` is comparatively easy. Try something like:

```
class ForkOut extends PrintStream {
    // The other stream to write to.
    final PrintStream[] others;

    public ForkOut(PrintStream o1, PrintStream... others) {
        super(o1);
        this.others = others;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) {
        super.write(b);
        // Echo every write to the other streams.
        for ( PrintStream o : others ) {
            o.write(b);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte[] buf, int off, int len) {
        super.write(buf, off, len);
        // Echo every write to the other streams.
        for ( PrintStream o : others ) {
            o.write(buf, off, len);
        }
    }
}

public void test(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    System.setOut(new ForkOut(System.out, new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"))));
    System.out.println("Hello again!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `System.setOut()` method redirects all outputs to the `System.out` Stream to the desired Stream(which in your case is the PrintStream `out`). You could consider writing the results into the file with the `out.print(String)` method and on the console with the `System.out.print(String)` method