# Postgres dump batch secondary backup directory

Tags: postgresql, batch-file, directory, backup

I'm running this script to backup a database. It works but I would like to add a secondary backup directory to get the output file in two different directories. Any help is appreciated..)

```
REM Set paths and database info
    set PGPASSWORD='postgre'
    set PGuser='postgres'
    set PGinstance='e3238s'
    set PGdump='F:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin\pg_dump'
    set BackupDir='F:/backup'
    set BackupName='DB_BK'

REM Build a datetime stamp
    set DateTime='%DATE:~-4%_%DATE:~-7,2%_%DATE:~-10,2%_%TIME:~0,2%_%TIME:~3,2% _%TIME:~6,2%'
echo %DateTime%

REM Backup 
    "%PGdump%" -f "%BackupDir%\%BackupName%%DateTime%.sql" --format plain -U %PGuser% -v %PGinstance%
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite unrelated to Postgres, and more related to how you'd output to two files in the same run.

You could use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625571/how-to-redirect-a-output-of-a-command-to-two-files#answer-625576), which in your case, becomes:

```
REM Backup 
    "%PGdump%" --format plain -U %PGuser% -v %PGinstance% >  "%BackupDir%\%BackupName%%DateTime%.sql" & type "%BackupDir%\%BackupName%%DateTime%.sql"  >> "%SecondaryBackupDir%\%BackupName%%DateTime%.sql"
```