# How can I direct standard output into two pipes?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, tee, output-redirect

I need to do two separate things with the standard output stream of my program: Say, direct it into two pipes, or print it to the terminal and direct it into a pipe. But - none of these things is directing it into a file.

If I wanted a pipe + a file, I would use the `tee` command: `myprog | tee out.txt | another_command`, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/625571/1593077). But what if none of the two actions are writing to a file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use process substitution in `bash` to do that. Say you want to redirect output from `myprog` to two separate entities to read on, use the `>(..)` along with `tee`

```
myprog | tee >(prog1) >(prog2)
```

See [Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) or the [man bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) docs for more information.

Comment: ...as written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10218282)

Comment: @mkrieger1: Didn't see the sub-duplicate. Will make the answer a community Wiki

Comment: @Inian; Indeed, the direct duplicates' answers are inferior to yours :-)